# google apps script New notation service fails with doPost

Tags: google-docs, google-apps-script

I tested the easy example https://developers.google.com/apps-script/class_fileupload?hl=es
to upload file using apps script.

I used two different spreadsheet but the error is the same. I cut and paste the example.
doGet seems run ok, but when submit button is pressed the error message "An unexpected error occurred" appear.

Well, I discovered the problem is..... the url call:
The publish system says now you use this format: https://docs.google.com/macros/s/[ID service]/exec
But if you change by the old format http://docs.google.com/macros/exec?service=[ID service] doGet and doPost work well.

I don't know what's happend. Why the new apps script publishing system appear with a format that seems it doesn't work well (https://docs.google.com/macros/s/[ID service]/exec).

May be, it is an issue.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I can replicate the problem and I've opened a [bug](http://code.google.com/p/google-apps-script-issues/issues/detail?id=1403) to track it.

Answer (score 0):

The bug is solved.

Google has changed the system of the apps publication (GAS) and the editor/debugger inteface.

Regards,

Answer (score 0):

The old URL format does not work on Chrome Browser Version 24.0.1312.57. 
In Firefox 12.0 work fine.